# How to delete an envelope from the docusign api?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using an esignature api.

I want to delete the envelope using the esignature api.

The deletion was not found in EnvelopesApi.

How to delete an envelope from the docusign api?

Comment: Can you please share why you want to delete an envelope, and are you planning to delete Draft or sent envelope?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Envelopes: update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update) API to **Void** envelopes which will make it so no one can sign and invalidate the transaction.

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}

{
    "status":"voided",
    "voidedReason":"voided for incorrect recipient"
}
```

By default DocuSign envelopes are stored in your account for 2 years I believe, however if you want you can **Purge** any given envelope which will remove it forever.  To purge a document you can use the same API as above.

Comment: Hi, this only works for sent and delivered envelopes.

Comment: Even then, it doesn't work even if the envelope has been sent or delivered.